# Fixed coordinate of a vector on a hypersphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, vectors

I have some ambiguity concerning the basic geometric interpretation of vectors in a Hilbert space. I’m not really sure whether the physics stack exchange is the right board, but I guess, some of you might have a answer for me?
Here it goes: When I have a vector which lies on a random point on the unit sphere of $\mathbb{C}^3$, I can write it as
$$
\vert \psi \rangle = c_1 \vert 1\rangle + c_2 \vert 2 \rangle + c_3 \vert 3 \rangle \, \, \,\text{with} \, \, \, \sum |c_i|^2=1
$$
When fixing one coordinate for whatever reason, I may choose some $ b \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|b|<1$ and have the 
$$
\vert \psi’ \rangle = c_1 \vert 1\rangle + c_2 \vert 2 \rangle + b \vert 3 \rangle \, \, \,\text{with} \, \, \, \sum |c_i|^2=1-|b|^2
$$
being random vectors on the circle of the sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-|b|^2}$. Can I identify this circle of the sphere with the unit sphere of $\mathbb{C}^2$ compressed to radius $\sqrt{1-|b|^2}$? And if so, can I even generalise this to large dimensional hyper spheres such that fixing one of the random vector components is basically equivalent to reduce the dimension of the regraded hypersphere by one and at the same time shrink it to radius $\sqrt{1-|b|^2}$?

The reason I’m asking is because I kind of want to know how fixing of one coordinate within a spastic also Ensemble of states affects the overall conclusion for that modified ensemble.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I think you can, but "Yes" isn't really an answer, I guess. I see no reason for it not to be true.

Comment: You may only have to be careful when choosing a coordinate s.t. $1-b^2 = 0$. Then you will only get a point independent of the dimensionality you had before. EDIT: You took $|b| < 1$, so you have already taken care of it.